# python: functions in class scope

Tags: python, oop

I am just playing around with the language, but wonder if it is possible to use functions defined within a scope of the class without explicitly defining `self` as the first argument.

I understand the "proper" way to implement a class might be

```
class minimal:
    variable = 1    
    def add(self,x,y):
        return x+y
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.value = self.add(x,self.variable)

m = minimal(1)
print m.value
--> 2
```

However, if I define and apply `add` in a similar way as `variable` (in the scope of the class), then I get an error (expected):

```
class minimal:
    variable = 1
    def add(x,y):
        return x+y
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.value = self.add(x,self.variable)

m = minimal(1)
print m.value
--> TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Is there a way around this? Or this is it generally advised that everything be defined with explicit reference to `self` (i.e. `self.variable=1` defined in the `__init__` method and `add` defined with `self` as first argument)?

**Edit** `__init__` method corrected to assign to `self.value` in the second case instead of trying to return a value (unintentional).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod), but [don't](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: this is great, thanks, but the second article says: "But do note that calling a classmethod involves an additional memory allocation that calling a staticmethod or function does not." Doesn't that argue for using the `@staticmethod` approach you linked to first?

Comment: You missed the third paragraph.

Comment: That is precisely how I thought of it when I saw the question. Sure, it's possible, but *please don't*. And that Python Is Not Java article is about the best on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the first argument is arbitrary. The object is always passed as the first argument. When you declare `add`, the object will be passed as `x`. When you call `self.add(x,self.variable)`, `self` is bound to  `x` in add, `x` in `__init__` is bound to `y` in `add` and `self.variable` is passed as a third argument, which `add` isn't declared to take.

```
class minimal:
    variable = 1
    def add(x,y, *args):
        print('x: %s;\ny: %d;\nargs: %s;\n' % (x, y, args))
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.add(x,self.variable)
```

> ```
> >>> minimal(2)
> x: <__main__.minimal object at 0x1006e6e90>;
> y: 2;
> args: (1,);
> ```

In summary, even if you do away with `self` as the first argument, you still get the object passed as the first argument to methods.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- I understand that this was the nature of the error statement above. Somewhat surprising behavior...

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the method as being static, try this:

```
class minimal:
  variable = 1

  @staticmethod
  def add(x,y):
    return x+y

  def __init__(self,x):
    print self.add(x,self.variable)

m = minimal(1)
```

Though I changed this so your **init** method doesn't return a value, which it shouldn't.